# Is unsubscribe needed if an Observable uses an async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I need to determine whether two different approaches for handling Observables are equally valid, or if one will cause memory issues.

In the following example, `foo$` and `bar` are template variables that receive their values from a service. Each has its own Observable. In the component, `bar` is explicitly given its value from a subscription and later ends that subscription in `OnDestroy()`. `foo$`, however, does not explicitly subscribe to a service but rather uses an `async` pipe in the template.

Are `foo$` and `bar` both valid ways of displaying the service data, or is `foo$` problematic because there is no unsubscribing for memory cleanup?

**ExampleService:**

```
Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
    get foo$(): Observable<string> {
        return data.from.api;
    }

    get bar$: Observable<string> {
        return data.from.api;
    }
}
```

**ExampleComponent:**

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <div>{{ foo$ | async }}</div>
        <div>{{ bar }}</div>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public foo$ = this._exampleService.foo$;
    public bar = '';
    private _destroy$ = new Subject();

    constructor(private _exampleService: ExampleService) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this._exampleService.bar$
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
            .subscribe(bar => this.bar = bar);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel subscriptions.
     */
    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this._destroy$.next(true);
        this._destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentionned in the doc: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe,: " When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks." Both options are valid, they each have their pros/cons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From angular team

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

So the async pipe takes care of subscribing and unwrapping the data as well as unsubscribing when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

NO, The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.