# Does async pipe unsubscribes from an observable defined in a service and pointed to from a component variable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a BehaviourSubject defined in a service, and i point to that subject with a variable i define in another component, in that component's view i subscribe to the subject using that variable, example:

service:

```
public exampleSubjebt$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

component.ts:

```
ngOninit() {
let someVariable = this.service.exampleSubject$;
}
```

component's view:

```
<app-something [options]="someVariable | async"></app-something>
```

My question is, does the fact the the observable sits in the service and I call it directly from there using the variable, make it so that the async pipe will not unsubscribe on the component's destruction?

Comment: I assume someVariable is actually a property on the class?

Comment: yeah that variable is a property in the class.

Comment: `async` will always unsubscribe automatically. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033098/is-unsubscribe-needed-if-an-observable-uses-an-async-pipe

Answer (score 4):

The subscription lies into the component, not into the service so the async pipe will unsubscribe correctly when the component get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does unsubscribe. The [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) is an angular directive, so it has all the lifecycles a component has. In the [implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) i have found the following:

```
class ObservableStrategy implements SubscriptionStrategy {
  createSubscription(async: Observable<any>, updateLatestValue: any): SubscriptionLike {
    return async.subscribe({next: updateLatestValue, error: (e: any) => { throw e; }});
  }

  dispose(subscription: SubscriptionLike): void { subscription.unsubscribe(); }

  onDestroy(subscription: SubscriptionLike): void { subscription.unsubscribe(); }
}
```

In the ngOnDestroy they call the dispose

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this._subscription) {
    this._dispose();
  }
}
```